# How to generate Gherkin Scripts for Automation Testing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, bdd, specflow

I'm using BDD frame work for my automation project with C# in visual studio. For this project I have written my feature files by using gherkin syntax. But now my requirement is to generate them automatically, is there any way to do that?

Comment: generate them from what? testrails? excel?

Comment: From excel where manual test cases are written. But not in Given, When, Then.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to automate the tests using excel, rather than Gherkin, as the input?

Comment: No, I want to automate Gherkin tests but instead of writing the steps in Give, When, Then using gherkin syntax. I'm looking to find a way to generate those steps. My be by converting manual test cases to gherkin steps or by any record and play back tool. Is there any way to generate the gherkin steps instead of writing them?

Comment: This is not what Gherkin was designed for. There is no way to automatically write scenarios. Gherkin is 1) documentation; and 2) automated tests. The "automated tests" part is the secondary benefit. The main benefit is that Gherkin describes business processes, and is a form of writing requirements.